# iOS 11: Can't seem to cast CoreData fetch results to an array in Swift 3

Tags: arrays, swift, core-data, casting

I am implementing coreData. I am saving color and string to CoreData. I have created an NSManagedObject class with two variables -

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class addednotes: NSManagedObject
{
@NSManaged var sNote: String
@NSManaged var sPriorityColor: UIColor

}
```

In the CoreData I have created two attributes, sNote of type String and sPriorityColor of type 'Transformable'

[image]
[image]

Next in tableViewController, I am fetching the results and storing them in array of type `[addednotes]`

```
var allnotes = [addednotes]()
```

In `viewDidAppear()`, I am fetching the data:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "AllNotes")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    do {
        allnotes  = try moContext.fetch(request) as! [addednotes]
          print(allnotes.count)



    }
    catch {
        //Process error
    }

    tableView.reloadData()
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

}
```

I am able to save the data to the CoreData but when it comes to fetching it, it gives me this error:

> Could not cast value of type 'todoquick.AllNotes' (0x6040002c0cc0) to 'todoquick.addednotes' (0x10dd2f800).

With error shown on this line:

```
 allnotes  = try moContext.fetch(request) as! [addednotes]
```

What is the issue? Help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Check the class defined for your AllNotes entity in the data model editor - looks like it is set to class `AllNotes`, whereas your class definition is for `addednotes`.

Comment: Thank you:) It worked!!!